# Does current flow through the potentiometers of buck and boost converters?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost, switching-regulator

I'm working on a project where I'm replacing the trimpots on a buck converter and a boost converter with proper potentiometers. The new potentiometers will be wired to the converters instead of soldered directly on, so this poses a problem: What wire gauge should I use?

Let's say my loads will be maximally drawing 10A. Does that mean I need 16-14AWG wire to attach the potentiomters? I don't think so but I don't totally understand these things. My current understanding is that the potentiometer acts as a voltage divider and it is the center pin which tells the chip how to limit voltage or current by being at a certain voltage.

The answer may be that it depends on the converter but I think there is a general pattern here. To give an example though, I'll be working on this [Chinese converter](http://www.mhinstek.com/product/html/?109.html) ([Google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mhinstek.com%2Fproduct%2Fhtml%2F%3F109.html&edit-text=)) **Update:** [This post](http://cr4.globalspec.com/comment/1018737/Re-Power-Supply-DC-DC-Step-Up-Converter-Problem) is the most information I can find on it.

As I understand it, it's based on the [UC3842A](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/UC3842A-D.PDF) SMPS controller driving at least one power MOSFET (I also see a big N-channel and then the smaller BU806 NPN.) I don't know if that's enough information to answer my question though. It seems like, if it works the way I think it does, it's pins 2 and 3 on the UC3842A which read the potentiometers.

Another example is the [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf)-based boards. I suspect they work in a similar way (and are a bit easier to understand.) There's one more board/chip that I'm interested in but I don't have any information on it yet since it's not in my possession and there's very little details online. If it's okay, I'll leave the ebay link [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-CC-300W-Step-Down-Buck-Converter-7-32V-To-0-8-28V-Power-module-SC-/251874659840?hash=item3aa4e64e00:g:uHkAAOSwQJhUiXTj).

Comment: To be sure what you're talking about, you should add schematics (or parts of it as image) and links to datasheets.

Comment: Good point. I added datasheets for the two chips that I know and a link to a post with an unofficial schematic and some explanation.

Comment: A trimpot cannot take much current let alone 10A which would release the magic blue smoke instantly, so why would swapping them out for external pots require big wire?

Comment: That's clever; it would not.

Comment: Variable resistors obey Ohm's law, more or less, as you'd expect, more or less.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes, but how does that help answer the question? The question is how much current is flowing through it and Bence and JIm have answered that.

Comment: He means that, given the two resistors in series from the output voltage to the ground. So if you apply Ohm's law, you will get the current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the potentiometers act as a variable voltage divider, so you can change the output voltage of the converter whenever you like. This voltage divider is connected to the Feedback (usually this pin is named as "Feedback") pin of converter IC, providing feedback for the regulation loop.

[image]

The datasheet usually contains information about this pin's bias current. In case of the LM2596, it is typically 10nA.

[image]

The feedback resistors are also recommended in the \$ k\Omega \$ range, reducing current flow.

Comment: Thank you. I will compare this with the UC3842A. And yes, the pot that I have on one of these  LM2596 boards is 10Kohm. On the UC3842A, it's 100Kohm.